# An application is dependent on result of the other applications, how we can achieve this in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, executorservice, concurrent.futures

The following question is asked in the interview. 
Let different services call each other, there is one service A, it is calling service B which takes 20 secs. **Service A** is also calling **Service C** and **Service D**, both take 25 secs, 20 secs respectively. When Service A gets the response from B, C, D it has to return the response to the front end. How you will achieve this.

I think the interviewer meant to ask for multithreading or ExecutorService from concurrency. So I told that we can use `Future` Object Return from the Callable Interface. For that, I have written the following code:
The following code is working and returning result: 45, which is correct.

Is my approach correct when an application is dependent on the other application result? In real-world applications do we use this approach? Please let me know if there is any correction in the code?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Result{
    String applicationName;
    int result;
    public Result(String applicationName, int result){
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
        this.result = result;
    }
    public void add(int value){
        this.result += value;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
class ApplicationA implements Callable<Result>{
    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Future<Result>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Result>>();
        Future<Result> futureB = executorService.submit(new ApplicationB());
        list.add(futureB);
        Future<Result> futureC = executorService.submit(new ApplicationC());
        list.add(futureC);
        Future<Result> futureD = executorService.submit(new ApplicationD());
        list.add(futureD);

        Result result = new Result("ApplicationA", 12);
        for(Future<Result> future: list){
            try {
                Result result1 = future.get();
                result.add(result1.getResult());
            }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        return result;
    }
}
class ApplicationB implements Callable<Result>{
    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        return new Result("ApplicationB",10);
    }
}
class ApplicationC implements Callable<Result>{
    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(25000);
        return new Result("ApplicationC",11);
    }
}
class ApplicationD implements Callable<Result>{
    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        return new Result("ApplicationD",12);
    }
}
public class MultiApplicationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Result> futureA = executorService.submit(new ApplicationA());
        System.out.println(futureA.get().getResult());
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you writing for? If 8 or greater (it probably would be) I would expect knowledge of lambdas and modern concurrency constructs. The error handling is not good. And the naming is not good either. The strange executor in `main` is does nothing is a big red flag - makes me under whether you understand what asynchronous means. Your application will hang because you fail to shutdown any of the executors you create. TL;DR: absolutely not acceptable in the real world, in interview conditions it would raise many questions - for me at least.

Comment: you are just writing classes. A class and a Service is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Future` is a blocking operation.
[CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) on the other hand would provide you non-blocking mechanism. Along with `Future` interface, it also has `CompletionStage` interface which allows you to pipe multiple operations.

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture 
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello")
    .thenCompose(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> s + " World"));
```

It also provide you to fail gracefully, in case any of the requested service throws exceptions.

It is very similar to promises in Javascript.
[image]

Comment: How is `Future` blocking??

Comment: If the operation is not completed Future would block the current Thread which is being executed is blocked. Suppose you want to execute a task-1 in conjunction with task-2 and combine the result, meanwhile, you also want to some computation of your own. task-1.get would block the current thread. Also, Future does not support graceful exception handling ( It would complete itself, and blocks forever), whereas CompletableFuture chisels out these issues.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is incorrect. A `Future` is simply a handle on an async task. Nothing stops you spinning of task 1 and task 2 then doing your own computation and finally combining the results. Obviously calling `Future.get` is blocking, but it must be. `Future` is definitely not blocking - it's not _reactive_; which is a completely different concept.